# Analytic sets and Turing determinacy

Tags: computability-theory, descriptive-set-theory, determinacy

I wonder whether the following question have a positive answer within $ZFC$.

> **Question** If $\{A_n\}_{n\in \omega}$ is a sequence of  analytic sets so that $\bigcup_n A_n=2^{\omega}$, then there must be some $n$ so that $A_n$ has a pointed subset.

A pointed set is a perfect set $P$ of reals in which every member computes the representation of $P$.

Note that $PD$ implies a positive answer of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this fails under $V=L$.  If $P$ is a pointed perfect set and $X$ is a real, let $P(X)$ be the element of $P$ where at every split we choose according to the next bit of $X$.  So $X\oplus P \equiv_T P(X)$.

We'll build the $A_n$ via an $\omega_1$ length construction as follows.  At stage $\alpha$, we consider $P_\alpha$ the next pointed perfect set, and we choose $X_0, X_1, \dots$ which are self-constructible reals of $L$-rank at least $\alpha$ and computing $P_\alpha$.  We omit $P_\alpha(X_n)$ from $A_n$.

We define $A_n$ to consist of those reals which are never omitted.  So $Y \not \in A_n$ iff there is a well-founded $L_\alpha \in \Delta^1_1(Y)$ realizing $Y$'s omission, which is $\Pi^1_1$.  By appropriate choice of $X_n$, no real is omitted from more than one $A_n$, and so $\bigcup_n A_n = 2^\omega$.  But clearly we have diagonalized against any $A_n$ containing a perfect pointed set.

Comment: Thanks! Actually there are two disjoint $\Pi^1$-sets of Turing degrees ranging Turing degree cofinally under such assumption.